# android-market retrieve empty results

Tags: java, android, google-play

I wanted to harvest some data on specific apps in

Google play marketplace.

I have used this unofficial API:

https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Here is my code, that basically gets list of apps' names

and try to fetch other data on each app:

```
public void printAllAppsData(ArrayList<AppHarvestedData> dataWithAppsNamesOnly)
{       
    MarketSession session = new MarketSession();
    session.login("[myGamil]","[myPassword]");
    session.getContext().setAndroidId("dead00beef");

    final ArrayList<AppHarvestedData> finalResults = new ArrayList<AppHarvestedData>();

    for (AppHarvestedData r : dataWithAppsNamesOnly)
    {
    String query = r.name;
    AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                                    .setQuery(query)
                                    .setStartIndex(0).setEntriesCount(10)
                                    //.setCategoryId("SOCIAL") 
                                    .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                                    .build();

    session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
             @Override
             public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {

                      List<App> apps = response.getAppList(); 
                        for (App app : apps) { 
                                AppHarvestedData r = new AppHarvestedData(); 

                                r.title = app.getTitle();
                                r.description = app.getExtendedInfo().getDescription();
                                String tmp = app.getExtendedInfo().getDownloadsCountText();
                                tmp = tmp.replace('<',' ').replace('>',' ');
                                int indexOf = tmp.indexOf("-");
                                tmp = (indexOf == -1) ? tmp : tmp.substring(0, indexOf);
                                r.downloads = tmp.trim();
                                r.rating = app.getRating();
                                r.version = app.getVersion(); 
                                r.userRatingCount = String.valueOf(app.getRatingsCount()); 
                                finalResults.add(r);
                                }
                        }
             });
    session.flush();
    }

    for(AppHarvestedData res : finalResults)
    {           
            System.out.println(res.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Should I realyy call `session.flush();` at this point?

all my quesries return empty collection as a result,

even though I see there are some names as input.

It works fine when I send only one hard coded app name as a query.

Comment: This way is not effective. It is not an official API and it's developers can change or update several time, therefore you will need change your code or approach several time. I created an app with this unofficial API, first time it worked well, then after 1 month crashed, and again became working, then crashed again. And this API can retrieve information not about all applications on the Market. I think that the developers have their own database and they update it when they want. I decided to do not use this API.

Answer (score 0):

session.flush() close you session
you should open session for each query. pay attention the user can be locked for few minutes so you should have many users to to those queries.
if you have the AppId  you should use that query:

```
  String query = r.name;
    AppsRequest appsRequest = AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                                    .setAppId("com.example.android")               
                                    .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                                    .build();

    session.append(appsRequest, new Callback<AppsResponse>() {
             @Override
             public void onResult(ResponseContext context, AppsResponse response) {

                      List<App> apps = response.getAppList(); 
                        for (App app : apps) { 
                                AppHarvestedData r = new AppHarvestedData(); 

                                r.title = app.getTitle();
                                r.description = app.getExtendedInfo().getDescription();
                                String tmp = app.getExtendedInfo().getDownloadsCountText();
                                tmp = tmp.replace('<',' ').replace('>',' ');
                                int indexOf = tmp.indexOf("-");
                                tmp = (indexOf == -1) ? tmp : tmp.substring(0, indexOf);
                                r.downloads = tmp.trim();
                                r.rating = app.getRating();
                                r.version = app.getVersion(); 
                                r.userRatingCount = String.valueOf(app.getRatingsCount()); 
                                finalResults.add(r);
                                }
                        }
             });
    session.flush();
    }
```

if you want to download also screenshoot or images you should call this query:

```
    GetImageRequest? imgReq; imgReq = GetImageRequest?.newBuilder().setAppId(appId).setImageUsage(AppImageUsage?.SCREENSHOT).setImageId("0").build();

session.append(imgReq, new Callback<GetImageResponse>() {
@Override public void onResult(ResponseContext? context, GetImageResponse? response) {
Log.d(tag, "------------------> Images response <----------------"); if(response != null) {
try {
//imageDownloader.download(image, holder.image, holder.imageLoader);
Log.d(tag, "Finished downloading screenshot 1...");
} catch(Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
} else {
Log.e(tag, "Response was null");
} Log.d(tag, "------------> End of Images response <------------");
}
});
```

Comment: `session.flush() closes your session`- then how can I use it properlly? I don't know when the callback will be executed...

Comment: you can try to open many session with the same user at the same time (I don't try it). or you can to use few different accounts to open different sessions.

Comment: that's not practical. If I want to fetch 100 apps - I'll have to use 100 accounts?

Comment: No for each one you could send something like 10 queries and then you need to wait for some seconds. Just try it. You need to test the limitations